# colon missing where expected - gusek

Tags: linear-programming, glpk, mathprog

I'm new to this program called gusek, and i'm trying to run next formula:

```
Maximize objekt: 3x + 2y
Subject To objekt1: 2x + y <= 100 objekt2: x + y <= 80
Bounds x >= 0 x <= 40 y >= 0
End
```

It gives me "or_vaja.mod:1: colon missing where expected" error.

Any help?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: GMPL i guess @EliSadoff

Comment: I just tagged it as GLPK (a synonym for GMPL) so that should help out.

Comment: thanks :) @EliSadoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic error is due to writing "Maximize" uppercase instead of "maximize" lowercase.

And there are several other Errors in your sourcecode, like a missing * for the multiplication in you objective function, "Subject" in uppercase (you can also write the short version "s.t." for subject to), "End" in uppercase, missing the command delimiter ";" at the end of functions, and a properly definition of variables and their bound.

Have a look in the Help of Gusek and look at some examples.
Your lines should look more like this:

```
var x >= 0 <= 40;
var y >= 0;
maximize obj: 3*x + 2*y;
s.t. obj1: 2*x + y <= 100; 
s.t. obj2: x + y <= 80;
solve;
end;
```

Comment: kinda too late, but i'll still mark it as the right answer for your contribution!